How to force stop an application?
An important app on my phone does not work properly.
I was told that I should stop it and open it again. How to do this?
I already tried powering off and booting the phone, no avail.
Should I still stop the app somehow?

https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079646?hl=en

To force stop and hopefully fix a troublesome app on your Android smartphone:

Open Settings,
Select Apps
(You may also need to tap See all ### apps),
Tap the troublesome app,
Tap Force stop, and
Confirm by tapping OK.

You probably also need to clear the cache.
How to Force Stop Apps on Android
Other links:
How to Force Stop an App on Android
How to force close apps on your Android device
